# Calculate a point from the end of a line, on a particular angle and distance

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Considering a cartesian plane; There is a line from point **A** to **B**, at any angle from the horizontal axis. We need to draw another line from point **B** to **C**. The distance **d** of the new line is given as well as the angle **a** it will have from the first line. **We need to find the x and y coordinates of the point C**.

**Explanation:**
Lets suppose I have point A on the cartesian plane as such `{ Ax : 10 , Ay : 10 }`. I have another point B such that `{ Bx : 20 , By : 20}`. Now I need to find a point C in terms of `Cx` and `Cy`. While I have the length of the line BC or the magnitude of the vector BC; that is `d = 20`. And also the Angle AC that is `a = 135`. The Image attached also clarifies it further.

I found a solution to draw a line at 90 degrees from the end of a line, but it doesnt gives a solution for other angles. I also found a solution to find a point from a particular point at an angle relative to the X-axis, but it doesnt gives a solution for the angle being relative to a line instead.
[Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToA2k.png)

Comment: your drawing shows a as being 135. You need to calculate the "135"...

Comment: @Moti as I mentioned in the question, I already have the angle a and the distance d. For example a = 135 and d = 20 in the given image. All we need is to find the point C.

Comment: This question is clearly missing some context - what are points A,B? Are they arbitrary? What is it that you need to find then for the point $C$? Is it the locus? The question in it's current form is not clear at all

Comment: Are u familiar with the Cartesian system ? How x,y of a point are determined? Are you looking for (x,y) of C?

Comment: If you know points $A$ and $B$ and you know length of $BC$ along with angle between $AB$ and $BC$, one of the ways to find coordinates of point $C$, will be  to use vectors.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I have added an Explanation to better explain the situation, please reread the question for clarification.

Comment: @Moti yes exactly that is what I am looking for

Comment: @Math Lover I am trying to use vectors and I think they will have the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following an anticlockwise angular convention.

Let angle between AB and BC be  $\beta $ and let the slope of AB be $\phi$

$$ xC= xB + d \cos ( \pi + \phi -\beta) $$

$$ yC= yB + d \sin ( \pi + \phi -\beta) $$

Comment: Yes absolutely perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Position vector of point $A \,(x_1, y_1) \,$ and position vector of point $B \,(x_2, y_2) \,$ are known.

We assume position vector of point $C$ as $(x_3, y_3)$.

We now take two directional vectors from point $B$,

$\vec{a} = (x_1 - x_2) \hat{i} + (y_1-y_2)\vec{j}$

$\vec{c} = (x_3 - x_2) \hat{i} + (y_3 - y_2)\vec{j}$

We know $\vec{a}\,,$ the angle $\, \theta \,$ between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{c} \,,$  and we also know $|\vec{c}|$.

So, $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c} = |\vec{a}| \, |\vec{c}| \, \cos \theta$

This gives one equation in $x_3, y_3$.

We also know,

$|\vec{c}| = \sqrt{(x_3-x_2)^2 + (y_3-y_2)^2} \,$ and that is your second equation in $x_3, y_3$.

As you have two equations in two variables, you should be able to find $(x_3, y_3)$.